# Super-simple test code: ok in interpreter, NameError when executed as file?

Tags: python

This function newdef() works flawlessly in interpreter, but when executed as a file it throws a NameError. Can someone tell me why?

```
myuser$ cat r2.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

def newdef():
    a = input('say yes\n')
    if a == 'yes':
        print('he said yes')
    else:
        print('he said something else')


newdef()
```

Executed from commandline:

```
myuser$ ./r2.py
say yes
yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./r2.py", line 11, in <module>
    newdef()
  File "./r2.py", line 4, in newdef
    a = input('say yes\n')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'yes' is not defined
myuser$
```

If i copy / paste the function into iPython interpreter and execute it there it works.

Comment: Oh no... you're using the _old_ python...  :(

Comment: woh, thx... seems you're right. When i change the shebang to '/usr/bin/env python3' it works... i wasn't aware of this version quirks anymore as a i have an  alias python='python3.6' line in my .bashrc, and until now i didn't have such problems...